# Membership Report Issues

Tags: civimember, civireport

I have a discrepancy of 15 contacts between reports and need help figuring out where the error is. The Membership Summary is showing 1,108 members and yet the Membership Detail Report is showing only 1,093 records. Can someone please tell me why there is a discrepancy and how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome!  Unfortunately, this isn't enough information to answer your question.  Could you edit your question to show some screenshots of your filters and especially your grouping on the summary report?  Are you perhaps grouping by member, and 15 members have 2 memberships?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Jon. I would also guess that there are contacts in your database who have more than one membership. Membership reports are based on the object membership, so they count these rather than only the contacts attached to them. But screenshots would be helpful.